# How can I combine this php statement to get the results of multiple variable inputs?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is my WordPress query but is not a wordpress related question. It shows the posts that have meta_key as *extra1* and meta_value as *test*

```
<?php $customkey1 = extra1; ?>
<?php $customvalue1 = test; ?>
<?php query_posts('meta_key=' . $customkey1 . '&meta_value=' . $customvalue1 . '');  ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My question is how can I still show the posts that have `extra1` as metakey and `test` as metavalue but also the posts that have `extra2` as metakey and `test2` as metavalue in the same query. A combination of two or more variables.

Comment: I've no time to answer the question, just a comment: why do you put <?php ?> for every line???

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a wordpress-specific question, because query_posts is a wordpress function.

Comment: Probably beacuse it's a wordpress theme file which is mixed with Html. Not saying you should do that, though.

Comment: @crimson_penguin Yes, it definitely is.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to combine the results of two queries? [Check this out](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) You may just need to make two query objects and combine them.

Something like (note, I do not have WordPress installed, nor use WordPress. But assuming that its API is not a lie):

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$the_second_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// The Second Loop
while ( $the_second_query->have_posts() ) : $the_second_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Note: This is hideous, ugly, and will work but in most cases should be considered WRONG by professionals. More elegantly, at least I would use a function to parse the post. Most elegantly, I would do what has been suggested elsewhere, encapsulate the combined query in a MySQL bit. But given the op's knowledge, this seems to be the "best approach" for quickly solving this problem, hopefully only once. (Repeated application of this approach will turn it into a messy nightmare)

Comment: i.e. make a new WP_Query object with each query you want. Go through each query and add its results to a single array that holds all the posts you want. Then output the posts.

Comment: It would probably be better to write a custom query with the WP_Query object which does the selecting directly in mysql instead of having to put them together in php.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. can you post me an example of what you are reffering ?

Comment: @Ancide Agreed, but that requires knowledge of PHP, MySQL, and programming. Something that these CMSes generally try to avoid forcing their users to have.

Comment: This will show the titles of first args query and after the second's right? How can I show the title of the posts that satisfy both queries?

Comment: Of course. This is after all a site about programming :) And the question was tagged with mysql and php.

Comment: "satisfy both queries" as in the intersection (result MUST have extra1,test AND extra2, test2) or the union (result has either extra1, test OR extra2, test2) of the queries? Or are you talking about one complex query with multiple parameters? If so, look at example 4 and example 5 on the link I provided. If those do not make sense to you, hire a programmer for $20 to fix this one particular issue.